# How to get all the symbols `x` for which `f[x]` is defined?

Tags: symbols

Assume that definitions like the following are in place:

```
f[alpha] = "artichoke";
f[bravo] = "beet";
f[charlie] = "celery";
...
f[yankee] = "yam";
f[zulu] = "zucchini";
```

etc.  (Also assume that all the symbols `alpha`, `bravo`, `charlie`, ..., `yankee`, `zulu` evaluate to themselves.)

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all the symbols for which `f` is defined.  IOW, *given* `f`, I'm looking for a way to get the list of symbols

```
{alpha, bravo, charlie, ..., yankee, zulu}
```

(Note that, for the query I'm interested in here, the values associated with the definitions are irrelevant.)

The closest I've found is to somehow scrape the output of `Information[f]` (or `Definition[f]`), which strikes me as a horrible prospect.

Is there a more civilized approach?

Comment: Try `First[#][[1, 1]] & /@ DownValues[f]`.

Comment: Equivalent to `Level[DownValues[f], {4}]`.

Comment: @Virgil. Nice, but not always equivalent. Try f[alpha]={{beta}}. Then Level[DownValues[f], {4}] returns {alpha, beta}.

Comment: @Virgil This DownValues[f][[All, 1, 1, 1]] will behave slightly faster for large DownValues.

Comment: @FredSimons: good point.

Comment: @RolfMertig: good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barbarism can be avoided through judicious application of `DownValues`. Using [RolfMertig](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29/rolf-mertig)'s suggestion, you can get what you want with

```
f[alpha] = "artichoke";
f[bravo] = "beet";
f[charlie] = "celery";
...
f[yankee] = "yam";
f[zulu] = "zucchini";

DownValues[f][[All, 1, 1, 1]]

(* -> {alpha, bravo, charlie, ..., yankee, zulu} *)
```